# Question on power, If 2x^2x^2x^2x... =4 Solve for x

Tags: power-series, exponentiation, systems-of-equations, exponential-sum

I've seen this random example,
in which

[image]
can anyone give me clue how to solve for $ x $ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's, unfortunately, not a particularly well-defined problem, as infinite power towers aren't always well defined. However, if we want to apply algebraic techniques anyhow, notice that we can write it as
$$2x^{\left(2x^{2x^{2x\ldots}}\right)}=4$$
where the inner expression on the left is equal to four for a solution, giving
$$2x^4=4$$
which is easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$
2x^{2x^{2x^{..}}}=4 \longrightarrow 2x^4=4
$$
$$
x^4=2
$$

I think you can do the rest.

Comment: $2x^{2x^{2x^{..}}}=y=4 \longrightarrow 2x^y=4 \longrightarrow  2x^4=4$

Comment: @vadim123 whoops, my bad. Forgot to divide the 4 (divided both sides by 2).